# Problemas con llave foranea al ingresar nuevo registros

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ayuda por favor, estoy intentado ingresar datos a una tabla Empleadnom con 2 llaves foraneas de otras dos tablas, la creacion no tiene inconvenientes, con este codigo:

```
 eng = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:000@localhost:000/bdnomprueba2", echo=True)

    Base = declarative_base()
    metadata = MetaData()

    class Empleadnom(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'empleadnom'

        id_Emp = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
        numdocEmp = Column(Integer())
        nombreEmp = Column(VARCHAR(45))
        apellEmp = Column(VARCHAR(45))
        celEmp = Column(Integer())
        fechaingEmp = Column(Date())
        cargoEmp = Column(VARCHAR(45))
        sbmEmp = Column(Float(45))
        id_eps = Column (Integer, ForeignKey('epsnom.id_eps'))
        epsnom = relationship ("Epsnom", backref=backref('empleadnom', order_by=id_Emp ))

    > class Epsnom(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'epsnom'

        id_eps = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
        nit_eps = Column(Integer())
        nombre_eps = Column(VARCHAR(100))
        ciudad_eps = Column(VARCHAR(45))
        tel_eps = Column(VARCHAR(45))
        numdocEmp = Column(Integer())

    Base.metadata.create_all(eng)
```

> Pero al tratar de agregar un registro:

```
def Agregar():
    print("Estas en la Opcion Agregar Empleados ")

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=eng)
    session = Session()

    empleado=Empleadnom(numdocEmp = input("Digite el numero de Documento del Empleado"),
                       nombreEmp = input("Digite el primer nombre del empleado"),
                       apellEmp = input("Digite el primer apellido del empleado"),
                       celEmp = input("Digite el numero del celular del empleado"),
                       fechaingEmp = input("Digite la fecha de ingreso del empleado"),
                       cargoEmp = input("Digite el cargo  del empleado"),
                       sbmEmp = input("Digite el salario basico mes del empleado"),
                       id_eps = input("Digite el nombre de La EPS"),
                       id_afp = input("Digite el nombre de la AFP"))


    session.add(empleado)
    session.commit()
    session.close()
```

> Me genera el siguiente error, no se que me falta o que me sobra, gracias por su colaboracion:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bdnomprueba2`.`empleadnom`, CONSTRAINT `empleadnom_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_eps`) REFERENCES `epsnom` (`id_eps`))') [SQL: 'INSERT INTO empleadnom (`numdocEmp`, `nombreEmp`, `apellEmp`, `celEmp`, `fechaingEmp`, `cargoEmp`, `sbmEmp`, id_eps, id_afp) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: ('555', 'adsd', 'asdsad', '222', '2015-01-01', 'sdsad', '1500', '1', '2')]
```

Comment: ¿Existe el `id_eps=1` en `epsnom`?

Comment: no que yo sepa,

Comment: Y Listando la tabla en mysql no aparece ese registro

Comment: Ahí entonces el problema. Saludos..

Comment: Explicame esa parte por favor?

Comment: debe existir id_eps=1, por??

Comment: El error al menos dice eso: `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (bdnomprueba2.empleadnom, CONSTRAINT empleadnom_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (id_eps) REFERENCES epsnom (id_eps))`, y si te fijas en el código: `id_eps = Column (Integer, ForeignKey('epsnom.id_eps'))`.  No sé la lógica particular e este caso, pero lo cierto es que a menos que des de alta el `id_eps=1` en `epsnom` te segirá dando el error.

Comment: Pero si ya tengo ese id_eps, como igual a llave primaria, como haria eso, o
 en cambio deberia  en ves de id_eps=True, seria id_eps=1, ?

Comment: >  class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    order_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('users.user_id'))
    user =  relationship("User", backref=backref('orders', order_by=order_id))
    > def __repr__(self):
        return "Order(user_id={self.user_id}, " \
                      "shipped={self.shipped})".format(self=self)

Comment: si miras este ejemplo

Comment: Te aclaro que no se lo que es `Epsnom`, me guío únicamente por el código. Lo que ocurre tal como tienes configurados los objetos: si quieres dar de alta un  `Empleadnom` e indicarle un `id_eps`, este último debe existir en `Epsnom`. En tu ejemplo estás queriendo crear el empleado `555` con el `id_eps=1` que por lo que  dices no existe en `Epsnom`. O bien das de alta en primer lugar  el `Epsnom` con id 1 y luego das de alta el Empleado, o fijate si puedes cargar como vacío o NULL el id_eps del empleado.

Comment: Amigo, como puedes ver epsnom es el nombre de la tabla de la clase Epsnom

Comment: Si miras el script (empleadnom y epsnom) son los nombres de la dos tablas  y id_eps es llave primaria en epsnom y al mismo tiempo llave foranea en empleadnom

Comment: Viejo, ya entendi, disculpame, sucede que si epsnom no contiene ningun registro me genera error al dar de alta empeladnom.